# A question about interface inheritance in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, linq, inheritance

Let's take the interface `IQueryable<T>` for example:

```
public interface IQueryable<T> : IQueryable, IEnumerable;
```

Since IQueryable in turn implements IEnumerable:

```
public interface IQueryable : IEnumerable;
```

why in the first declaration, IQueryable has to explicitly implement IEnumerable as well? This is different from class inheritance where you do not have to explicitly inherit from a "grandparent"?

Comment: "IQueryable has to explicitly implement IEnumerable" -- Source?  And what do you mean by "explicitly implement"?

Comment: @strager: In the MSDN documentation, if you look at the declaration for IQueryable<T>, you will see something like the first declaration in my post, in which IQueryable<T> explicitly implements both IQueryable as well as IEnumerable, which I feel is redundant.

Comment: its because languages like c# support interface inheritance, but IL don't... so the compiler will explicitly implement all the interfaces directly for you when compiling the code.

Comment: See Pauli's explanation and my example.  You'll see how the documentation and metadata are generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not true.  I suspect you are right-clicking on these classes/interfaces in Visual Studio and clicking on "Go to definition," and this is what the *metadata* is telling you.  If you want to really understand what's happening, here's an example:

```
    public interface IAddTwo
    {
        int AddTwo(int x);
    }

    public interface IAddTwoOrThree : IAddTwo
    {
        int AddThree(int y);
    }

    public class AddTwoOrThree : IAddTwoOrThree
    {
        public int AddTwo(int q)
        {
            return q + 2;
        }

        public int AddThree(int z)
        {
            return z + 3;
        }
    }
```

Note that the last class only has to implement one interface (but that you get a compiler error if you leave off either method.

Create the above as a class library, add a reference by BROWSING to the resulting DLL (not by adding a reference to the project), and view the metadata for AddTwoOrThree.  You will see

```
AddTwoOrThree : IAddTwoOrThree, IAddTwo
```

Viola!  This is why you see what you are seeing on MSDN.  They show the metadata, not the way their coders wrote the code.

Comment: Hi, if you look under the Syntax section on the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx, the declaration for IQueryable<T> is similar to the first declaration in my post. Hence I have the question.

Comment: No.  Their help pages are simply displaying the metadata for what each class/interface implements, but you *do not* have to explicitly implement interfaces this way in your code.  If you are looking to understand what's going on, create a Visual Studio solution with two projects.  Create a Class Library with my code as above.  Then create a new project and add a reference to the DLL of the other by using BROWSE (not by adding a project reference).  Now instantiate AddTwoOrThree.  When you right click and choose "Go To Definition," you may be surprised at what you see.

Answer (score 3):

**Mentioning**  the grandparent (and higher ancestors) in the  declaration is **not strictly necessary, but** since the parent, being an interface,  didn't actually *implement* the grandparent, **its better** to mention the grandparent  in the declaration of the grandchild **to improve documentation** for the eventual implementer.

Thats why, in case of concrete implementations in the ancestry , you see the following in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.aspx):

```
public class Button : ButtonBase,IButtonControl
```

and not the  following ...

```
public class Button : ButtonBase,Control,Component,MarshalByRefObject,Object
```

Answer (score 1):

Its because Interface inheritance is a pure language sugar thing. When compiling to IL, the interface explicitly implements all the interfaces in the chain so looking at the signature for `IQueryable<T>` will end up looking like

```
.class public interface abstract auto ansi IQueryable<+ T>
    implements [mscorlib]System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1<!T>, System.Linq.IQueryable, [mscorlib]System.Collections.IEnumerable
{
}
```

And since most documentation is auto generated from metadata, and not the original sourcecode, it will end up showing the signature as its implementing all the interfaces directly, and not via inheritance. Which is basically how it is. The only reason YOU can take advantage of inheritance is because the compiler will end up creating the right signature for you, wiring up all the interfaces explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

The correct definition is:

```
public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable { }
```

The following was taken from Microsoft's Source RTMRel\ndp\fx\src\Core\System\Linq\IQueryable.cs\1305376\IQueryable.cs

```
    public interface IQueryable : IEnumerable {
        Expression Expression { get; } 
        Type ElementType { get; } 

        // the provider that created this query 
        IQueryProvider Provider { get; }
    }

#if SILVERLIGHT 
    public interface IQueryable<T> : IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable {
#else 
    public interface IQueryable<out T> : IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable { 
#endif
    } 

    public interface IQueryProvider{
        IQueryable CreateQuery(Expression expression);
        IQueryable<TElement> CreateQuery<TElement>(Expression expression); 

        object Execute(Expression expression); 

        TResult Execute<TResult>(Expression expression);
    } 

    public interface IOrderedQueryable : IQueryable {
    }

#if SILVERLIGHT
    public interface IOrderedQueryable<T> : IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable { 
#else 
    public interface IOrderedQueryable<out T> : IQueryable<T>, IOrderedQueryable {
#endif 
    }
```

Comment: Hi, if you look under the Syntax section on the MSDN page http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx, the declaration for IQueryable<T> is similar to the first declaration in my post. Hence I have the question.

Comment: don't post the source of .Net on a public forum like SO. It makes people unable to contribute to ie Mono if they have read sources like this. http://mono-project.com/Contributing *If you have looked at Microsoft's proprietary implementation of .NET or their shared source code (which is also proprietary), you will not be able to contribute to Mono. If you would like to contribute in this area, be careful to not look into them in Visual Studio debugging experience.*

Comment: @Pauli Østerø: I did not publish the source. I referenced the source, so anyone can look at it. I did post the interface definitions, which can be gathered from reflection or the Object Browser.

Comment: @Pauli Østerø: Based on my experience and my interptation, their meaning is...do not access proprietary code while contributing. You can read the code all day long. You can even use your knowledge gleamed from that reading, but you absolutely cannot use the actual source code as a reference nor any other tool to determine implementation details.