# C# : Transitive Inheritance

Tags: c#, multiple-inheritance

Is Inheritance a transitive relation in C#?

I am asking because I cannot understand why `IList<T>` implements `ICollection<T>` and `IEnumerable<T>` as `ICollection<T>` already implements `IEnumerable<T>`

Thanks for clarifying this for me.

Comment: you can find some answers in this similar [question][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1164757/why-arraylist-implement-ilist-icollection-ienumerable

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754923/a-question-about-interface-inheritance-in-net/4755044#4755044

Comment: This is also a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4817369/why-does-does-realy-list-implements-all-of-that-interfaces-not-just-ilistt/4818566#4818566

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK, it doesn't truly matter whether you declared `IList<T>` as:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T>, IEnumerable<T> { ... }
```

or simply as:

```
public interface IList<T> : ICollection<T> { ... }
```

Any class that wants to implement `IList<T>` will have to implement *all* of these interfaces, i.e. also the inherited ones.

Obviously, if you implemented this interface without implementing the `GetEnumerator` methods of the `IEnumerable`/`IEnumerable<T>` interfaces, you'd get a compiler error; this "proof" by demonstration should be enough to tell you that "interface inheritance" is transitive, indeed.

---

**Sidenote 1.** On a side note (and slightly off-topic), consider that you can also do the following:

```
class Base
{
    public void Foo() { ... }
}

interface IFoo
{
    void Foo();
}

class Derived : Base, IFoo 
{ }
```

`Derived` doesn't actually implement `IFoo`; its base class `Base` provides method `Foo`, but doesn't explicitly implement `IFoo` itself.

This compiles well, seemingly because all the methods that are required by the interfaces are there. (I'll leave it at that and leave the exact technical talk aside for now.)

The reason why I'm mentioning this seemingly unrelated phenomenon is that I like to think of interface inheritance in this way: You need to implement all methods required by the interfaces specified in the class declaration. So when I see

```
interface ICollection<T> : IEnumerable<T> { ... }
```

instead of saying, *"`ICollection<T>` inherits `IEnumerable<T>`"*, I could say to myself, *"`ICollection<T>` requires of all implementing classes that they implement `IEnumerable<T>`, also."*

---

**Sidenote 2.** To conclude this answer with yet another somewhat related anecdote (I promise it'll be the last one):

Some time ago I watched the video [*Inside .NET Rx and `IObservable`/`IObserver` in the BCL*](http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/Going+Deep/Kim-Hamilton-and-Wes-Dyer-Inside-NET-Rx-and-IObservableIObserver-in-the-BCL-VS-2010) on Channel 9. As you might now, those two new interfaces, coming from [Rx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/devlabs/ee794896), were introduced into the BCL with .NET 4. One peculiar thing is that when you subscribe an observer to an observable via `observable.Subscribe(observer)`, all you get back is some anonymous `IDisposable`. Why?

As the talkers explain in that video, they could have given the `IDisposable` a more descriptive name (such as `ISubscription`), via a type name "alias" defined as follows:

```
interface ISubscription : IDisposable {}
```

However, they finally decided against this. They figured that once an `ISubscription` is returned from the `Subscribe` method, it would no longer be obvious that the returned value needs to be `Dipose`d.

So that's another slightly problematic side of "interface inheritance" that one should keep in mind.

Answer (score 8):

It is transitive in all regards. Probably the tool that you use to look at the inheritance hierarchy has a certain way of displaying it. There is no way to unimplement an interface although you can implement it explicitly and thereby hide it from intellisense.

As the author of IList you can freely choose to derive from ICollection only or from ICollection and IEnumerable. IEnumerable would be redundant in this case and flagged by resharper.

Comment: Sorry for interrupting, but "and flagged by resharper" caught my attention. Resharper is only a tool, not a programming guru. It also flags many other things that if changed cause trouble later on. (eg. flags explicit declarations to be changed to implicit (var))

Comment: Yes. I only meant that sentence to give social proof that the folks programming resharper agree with me.