# Why Dbset implement IEnumerable when it already implements IQueryable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, iqueryable, dbset

Dbset seems to implement IEnumerable when it already has IQueryable, doesn't this makes the implementation of IEnum redundant as IQueryable already implements IEnum.

Comment: This is answered in this blog post by Eric Lippert: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces/

Comment: Possible duplicate of [A question about interface inheritance in .NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4754923/a-question-about-interface-inheritance-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, we should correct your terminology:

> IQueryable already implements IEnum.

`IQueryable` doesn't implement anything. It *inherits* `IEnum`, which means that every class that implements `IQueryable` must implement the members of `IEnum` as well as the members of `IQueryable`.

I think your question actually is this: why is `DbSet` defined as implementing `IEnum`, when it implements `IQueryable` so it has to implement `IEnum` anyway.

Technically, stating that `DbSet` implements `IEnum` is redundant.

Which leaves the question, Why would anyone unnecessarily state a base interface?

I'll quote this blog article by Eric Lippert: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2011/04/04/so-many-interfaces/

> Perhaps because they believe that doing so makes the code easier to understand and more self-documenting.
>
> Or, perhaps the developer wrote the code as
>
> interface I1 {}
>
> interface I2 {}
>
> interface I3 : I1, I2 {}
>
> and the realized, oh, wait a minute, I2 should inherit from I1. Why should making that edit then require the developer to go back and change the declaration of I3 to not contain explicit mention of I1? I see no reason to force developers to remove redundant information.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you need all rows of a specific table without any additional `where` clause, in `IEnumerable` format. in these circumstances, you can directly cast the `DbSet` to `IEnumerable`.

Comment: Sorry, but your answer is incorrect. You could directly cast `DbSet` to `IEnuemerable` whether it explicitly implements`IEnumerable` or whether it implicitly implements `IEnumerable` due to explicit implementations further up the hierarchy. See this DotNetFiddle for what I mean: https://dotnetfiddle.net/K7Nz78